# Rails4 - How to debug a user object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, byebug

How do I debug a user object?
I am using byebug. I want to access the name attribute but I am getting the class name user.
Kindly help
Thanks

```
[8, 17] in /home/ubuntu/workspace/converse/app/controllers/messages_controller.rb
    8:   end
    9: 
   10:   def new1
   11:     @msguser = User.where(id: params['recipients'])
   12:     byebug
=> 13:     @recid = params['recipients'] 
   14:   end  
   15:   
   16:   def create
   17:     recipients = User.where(id: params['recipients'])
(byebug) 
(byebug) @msguser
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, name: "sumar", email: "chuch@gmail.com", created_at: "2015-01-23 12:57:41", updated_at: "2015-01-23 12:59:13", password_digest: "$2a$10$xNvGKpPwspaeTd33QrTwuuLP0TesuuTmfbrUlFO7LDs...", remember_digest: nil, admin: false, date_of_birth: "1985-01-01 00:00:00", is_female: false, activation_digest: "$2a$10$nIwWkX2X8WugscC/Yre7KeWRIzw6ecNyA5hLn/xPw9C...", activated: true, activated_at: "2015-01-23 12:58:58", reset_digest: nil, reset_sent_at: nil, avatar_file_name: nil, avatar_content_type: nil, avatar_file_size: nil, avatar_updated_at: nil, country_id: 1, cover_file_name: nil, cover_content_type: nil, cover_file_size: nil, cover_updated_at: nil, intro: "hey">]>
(byebug) @msguser.name
"User"
(byebug)
```

I am expecting name: "sumar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about byebug but I believe it has nothing to do with it. If you want to debug a single user, you should put

```
@msguser = User.where(id: params['recipients']).first
```

That will give you one user instead of a collection of user(s). What I believe you were doing before was calling the name of the collection, which would be `User`. Another way of doing it is

```
@msguser = User.find(params['recipients'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Ohh I just noticed that `@msguser` is a relation not the record.

```
@msguser.first.name
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Could you please share what is a relation and how it is a relation and not a record?

Comment: That would work too. All depends on if he wants to have a relation and not just a single user.

Comment: A relation is (potentially) multiple records, kinda like an array but much more powerful. You have a relation because you used the `where` method and not `find`. Updating my answer.